# Finding the p-value between two numbers

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, p-value

I am trying to solve this example in statistics, but my results are different from the ones in the solution and I do not understand why. The example say:

> A study finds a test statistic $t$-value of $1.03$ for a t-test on a single population mean. The sample size is $11$, and the alternative hypothesis is $H_a:\mu \neq 5$. Using Table A-2 in the appendix, what range of values is sure to include the p-value for this value of $t$?

And the solution for this exercise is

> $$0.20 < p\text{ -value} < 0.50$$

But the solution I get is

> $$0.30 < p\text{ -value} < 0.40$$

Because if I go to the t-table, search for $ df=10 $ and search the values that contain $1.03$, it's between $0.879$ and $1.093$ which are $0.2$ and $0.15$. And after multiplying them by two because it's a two tailed test, I get my result.

My t-table:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result depends on wich table you read the result.

With my table

[image]

I get exacltly the result you are looking for

$0.2 < p <0.5$

Perhaps your table is more detailed

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer. I have updated my question and included a picture of the table which I have used

Comment: @Miji : your calculation is correct.